# unable to resolve class org.jblas.DoubleMatrix

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I run my groovy script in cmd,and got the following error：

```
unable to resolve class org.jblas.DoubleMatrix
```

The relevant code listed as following:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair
import org.jblas.DoubleMatrix
```

I use java(version 1.8.0_181) and groovy(version:3.0.0-alpha-3).The whole project was organized in maven.The main sources were implemented in java,and the test suite was implemented in groovy.The maven version is Apache Maven 3.5.4.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your man project:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jblas/jblas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jblas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jblas</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```